# SQLite database causing crash after beeing modified

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

My application was working fine until I modified the database to add 4 new columns ( studentN, teacherN, studentBD, and teacherBD).  Following the additions my app crashes when I call the on pause method:

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause(); 
    SaveVariableStatus();
    List<StatParcours> StatParcours = db.getAllSats();              
}
```

The problems seems to stack with getAllStats(), so here's the code: of the hole databasehandler:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =10;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "StatParcours";

    // Stats table name
    private static final String TABLE_STATS = "Statistique";

    // Stats Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    private static final String KEY_SPEED = "speed";
    private static final String KEY_DIST = "distance";
    private static final String KEY_COND = "condition";
    private static final String KEY_DURA = "duration";
    private static final String KEY_STUDN = "studentN";
    private static final String KEY_TEACHN = "teacherN";
    private static final String KEY_STUDBD = "studentBD";
    private static final String KEY_TEACHBD = "teacherBD";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_STATS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STATS + "(" 
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
                + KEY_DATE + " TEXT ," + KEY_DURA + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_SPEED + " DOUBLE," + KEY_DIST + " DOUBLE," 
                + KEY_COND + " TEXT," + KEY_STUDN + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_TEACHN + " TEXT," + KEY_STUDBD + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_TEACHBD + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_STATS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_STATS); 
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public List<StatParcours> getAllSats() {
        List<StatParcours> statList = new ArrayList<StatParcours>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_STATS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                StatParcours stat = new StatParcours();
                stat.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                stat.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
                stat.setDuration(cursor.getString(2));
                stat.setDistance(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3)));
                stat.setSpeed(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(4)));
                stat.setCondition(cursor.getString(5));
                stat.setStudentName(cursor.getString(6));
                stat.setStudentBirthDate(cursor.getString(7));
                stat.setTeacherName(cursor.getString(8));
                stat.setTeacherBirthDate(cursor.getString(9));

                // Adding contact to list
                statList.add(stat);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return statList;
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause    activity   {com.intellibatteries.conduiteaccompagnee/com.intellibatteries.conduiteaccompagnee.Maps}:   java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879)
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2835)
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2813)
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:244)
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
 07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):   at com.intellibatteries.conduiteaccompagnee.DatabaseHandler.getAllSats(DatabaseHandler.java:133)
 07-24    10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):    at com.intellibatteries.conduiteaccompagnee.Maps.onPause(Maps.java:396)
 07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):   at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5304)
 07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1229)
07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2866)
 07-24 10:20:48.834: E/AndroidRuntime(18746):   ... 12 more
```

Comment: crash => post stacktrace

Comment: Make sure you are updating database version after you have done with update.

Comment: What is getAllSats(DatabaseHandler.java:133) ?

Comment: I made  the update, uninstalled and installed the app several times, but I'm always getting the same problem.

Comment: getAllStats is a method used in teh databasehandler class (You can read the code above)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you can do:

1) make sure you call the implemented onUpgrade method from the DBHelper

2) if you are sure you don't need anything of your previous data and your phone is rooted, go to the root folder of your phone using something like "Root Explorer" or "ES File Explorer "with rooted mode, then go to /data/data/com.yourapp.data/ and then locate and delete the sql lite files

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

For distance or speed you have a `NULL` value in at least one row of the table "Statistique". When retrieving this value as string it is given as `null` to `Double.parseDouble()` which fails then.